# Django difficulty saving multiple model objects within save method

Tags: django, django-models

This is a hard question for me to describe, but I will do my best here.

I have a model that is for a calendar event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="event_account")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="event_location")
    patient = models.ManyToManyField(Patient)
    datetime_start = models.DateTimeField()
    datetime_end = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    event_series = models.ForeignKey(EventSeries, related_name="event_series", null=True, blank=True)
    is_original_event = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When this is saved I am overriding the save() method to check and see if the event_series (recurring events) is set.  If it is, then I need to iteratively create another event object for each recurring date.

The following seems to work, though it may not be the best approach:

```
def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        if self.event_series is not None and self.is_original_event is True :
            recurrence_rules = EventSeries.objects.get(pk=self.event_series.pk)

            rr_freq = DAILY                    
            if recurrence_rules.frequency == "DAILY":
                rr_freq = DAILY
            elif recurrence_rules.frequency == "WEEKLY":
                rr_freq = WEEKLY
            elif recurrence_rules.frequency == "MONTHLY":
                rr_freq = MONTHLY
            elif recurrence_rules.frequency == "YEARLY":
                rr_freq = YEARLY

            rlist = list(rrule(rr_freq, count=recurrence_rules.recurrences, dtstart=self.datetime_start))

            for revent in rlist:
                evnt = Event.objects.create(account = self.account, location = self.location, datetime_start = revent, datetime_end = revent, is_original_event = False, event_series = self.event_series)
                super(Event, evnt).save(*args, **kwargs)          

    super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, the real problem I am finding is that using this methodology and saving from the Admin forms, it is creating the recurring events, but if I try to get self.patient which is a M2M field, I keep getting this error:

```
'Event' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used
```

My main question is about this m2m error, but also if you have any feedback on the nested saving for recurring events, that would be great as well.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

If the code trying to access `self.patient` is in the save method and happens before the instance has been saved then it's clearly the expected behaviour. Remember that Model objects are just a thin (well...) wrapper over a SQL database... Also, even if you first save your new instance then try to access `self.patient` from the save method you'll still have an empty queryset since the m2m won't have been saved by the admin form yet.

IOW, if you have something to do that depends on m2m being set, you'll have to put it in a distinct method and ensure that method get called when appropriate

About your code snippet:

1/ the `recurrence_rules = EventSeries.objects.get(pk=self.event_series.pk)` is just redundant, since you alreay have the very same object under the name `self.event_series`

2/ there's no need to call `save` on the events you create with `Event.objects.create` - the `ModelManager.create` method really *create* an instance (that is: save it to the database).

Comment: Thanks Bruno!  I see the obvious redundancy in 1.  :)  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, I can setup another method for adding the M2M but where should it go and how would I call it to make sure it runs right after save?

Comment: Did some one able to solve this issue? I have asked the same question also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127679/django-model-override-save-function-not-updating-m2m-field-in-db)